# EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:5:1 caused by: No provider for Customer

Tags: angular

I am having issues getting my application to link together via routing I believe. Once I added `<router-outlet>` I started having issues of titles displaying twice and errors in the console saying:

`EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:5:1 caused by: No provider for Customer!`

Here is what I have and I also posted it on git [HERE](https://github.com/drewjocham/LibraryDemo1.git)

Ng-Module

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent, LibraryComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            {path: 'home', component: AppComponent},
            {path: 'mainPage', component: LibraryComponent},
            {path:'**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'}
        ])

    ],
    providers: [
        BooksService,
        CustomerService,
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {


}
```

AppComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/css/bootstrap.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {

    title = "Dummy login page"

}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>
        {{title}}
    </h1>

    <app-library></app-library>

</div>
```

app library component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-library',
    templateUrl: 'app/library/homePage/mainPage.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/css/bootstrap.css'],
})
```

Comment: Try to add `CustomerService` using `providers: [CustomerService]` in `appComponent`.

Comment: Remove `customer: Customer` from `constructor(customer: Customer, books:BooksService)` in your `CustomerService.ts`

Comment: @AvneshShakya I did that and got and error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property '8' of undefined`

Comment: Do you know what your code does?

Comment: `let book: IBook;` and then `book[someNumber]` is always will be error

Comment: @yurzui Are you referring to `let randomBook = [
            CustomerService.allBooks.filter((x => book[CustomerService.numberGenerator(0,5)])),` you are not being very clear.

Comment: Yeah, that is the place where you went wrong

Comment: @yurzui Ok I will look more into in thank you. but it should just be generating a number 0-5.